# jQuery get an image source encrypted/

Tags: jquery, image, upload

i kinda sorted out my problems with forms with using serializeArray, but as you may know it lacks of support for input/file, so decide to merge it with my serialized data. Now i create the object and everything i get the name of the file with .val(). But i can't the image source. For example i wanna do this:

```
        alert(jQuery('.inputBox#pic').attr(src));
        var obj = {'name'   : 'pic',
                   'value'  : jQuery('input#pic').src};
```

The only problem is that it doesn't work. I can't get the image source ready for upload. and without it i can't make a successful POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't post a file that way.

Even if you were able to get the complete source of the file (which is not even allowed in some browsers), it will be an address to a local file that you can not access.

The only way to post a file to the server is by posting the form that the upload control is in. There is no other way to get a file from the client computer, for security reasons. This means that you have to post the actual form on the page, you can't make an AJAX post.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [jQuery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which could be used to ajaxify your forms. It also [supports file input fields](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload).

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work quite well for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of that `alert()` call? And what are you trying to do with the `src` attribute? jQuery(selector).src doesn't do anything because you can't access the `img` element or its attributes that way.

If you want the value of `src`, then use:

```
var imgSrc = $('#pic').attr('src');
// or
var obj = {
    'name' : 'pic',
    'value' : $('#pic').attr('src');
};
```

I'm not sure how you plan on performing a file upload this way, but that's how you would do it. Still, I would suggest skimming the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) to make sure you understand the basics on jQuery DOM manipulation. You always use `.attr()` to get or set element attributes on a jQuery result. If you want to access actual element object or its properties, you need to use:

```
var elPic = $('#pic')[0];
// or
var imgSrc = $('#pic')[0].src;
```

Also, there's usually no point in mixing ID selectors with class selectors since IDs should be unique.

Lastly, I assume "`.attr(src)`" was a typo in your code, but if it wasn't then you need to brush up on your JavaScript so that you know the difference between a variable and a string literal. [String literals](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#String) need to be enclosed in either single or double quotes, otherwise JavaScript thinks you're passing the function a variable named `src` rather than the string "src".

Comment: that alert was part of the debug code in it. but i find information that it can't be done the way i want, so i abandon this as a workaround. Thanks for the help